# Extracting data from pivot table vba

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table to aggregate `"coverage"` on `"part"` only for accepted parts.

[image]

I want then to extract the `"sum of coverage"` to another sheet.
I wrote the following macro:

```
Sub Pull_data()
'Update the pivot table
Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
'clear all filters
Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Accepted").ClearAllFilters
'filters only accepted items
Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Accepted").CurrentPage = "YES"
'get the last row of the pivot table
Set PT = Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
With PT.TableRange1
    lngLastRow = .rows(.rows.Count).Row
End With
For i = 4 To lngLastRow
    'copy the coverage to destination sheet
    NEWi = i + 10
    Sheets("Destination").Range("G" & NEWi) = PivotTable.GetPivotData(data_field, Range("I" & i), “Coverage”)
Next i
End Sub
```

I get a run time error '424', object required on

```
Sheets("Destination").Range("G" & NEWi) = PivotTable.GetPivotData(data_field, Range("I" & i), “Coverage”)
```

Which would be the proper way to write that line?

Comment: Your pivot table object is `PT` and not `PivotTable`

Comment: Replacing 'PivotTable' with 'PT' still gives error ' run time error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error'

Comment: @L.Dutch instead of `Looping` try `TableRange2` (see my code below)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be :

```
Sheets("Destination").Range("G" & i + 10).Value = _
    pT.GetPivotData("Sum of coverage", "Part", Range("I" & i).Value).Value
```

Because `pT.GetPivotData` returns a Range!

Cleaned code :

```
Sub Pull_data()
    Dim pT As PivotTable
    Set pT = Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2")

    With pT
        '''Update the pivot table
        .PivotCache.Refresh
        '''clear all filters
        .PivotFields("Accepted").ClearAllFilters
        '''filters only accepted items
        .PivotFields("Accepted").CurrentPage = "YES"
        '''get the last row of the pivot table
        With .TableRange1
            lngLastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
            For i = .Cells(2, 1).Row To lngLastRow
                Debug.Print "i=" & i & "|" & Sheets("Pivot").Range("I" & i).Value
                '''copy the coverage to destination sheet
                Sheets("Destination").Range("G" & i + 10).Value = _
                    pT.GetPivotData("Sum of coverage", "Part", Sheets("Pivot").Range("I" & i).Value).Value
            Next i
        End With '.TableRange1
    End With 'pT
End Sub
```

Comment: this gives "Run time error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: @L.Dutch : my bad there a typo! ;)

Comment: @L.Dutch : What is the value of `data_field`?

Comment: the data I have are given in the image attached to the question. i.e. for part1 I want to extract the sum of coverage 30

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135972/discussion-between-l-dutch-and-r3uk).

Comment: @R3uK change your `With .TableRange1` to `With .TableRange2`

Comment: @ShaiRado : Are you sure about this? Because I think that it that case, we don't need the page fields to be included.

Answer (score 2):

You could try copying the entire Column from your `PivotTable` after it's filtered to your needs, with `TableRange2` , use the `Resize` to a single column, and then `Copy` and `PasteSpecial xlValues` to the destination worksheet.

If the code below takes the wrong column, you can also use the `Offset(0,1)` to get the right one.

```
With PT
    .TableRange2.Resize(.TableRange2.Rows.Count, 1).Copy
    Worksheets("Destination").Range("G14").PasteSpecial xlValues '<-- start Pasting from Row 14
End With
```

**Note**: if the code above takes the column to the left, try the code line below:

```
.TableRange2.Resize(.TableRange2.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(, 1).Copy
```